# Google+ api login

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to create a site where you can login with `Google+`, but I am having some problems understanding the Google+ API.

Can anyone explain to me how to fetch information, such as e-mail, name, id, etc.  or give me a good link for a site where I can find some documentation about this.

Before you suggest me to [this site](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) I have already read it but not finding out how to fetch info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ Sign-In provides users the ability to authorize your application to retrieve data from the Google APIs based on the scopes that you set for your button. When a user authorizes your app, the sign-in callback returns you an OAuth 2.0 access token. This token gives you the ability to queries any of the APIs that your scope granted access to, this is not limited to Google+ APIs. You pass your access tokens to the API when you make requests.

Basically, you read the prereqs and didn't continue reading the API docs for the lower level details specific to the API that you are interested in. In this case, it sounds like you want to retrieve a person's profile (A "[Person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)") by using the [`people.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) method. At the bottom of that page are code examples for a variety of languages.